# Error: "Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, http-get

An error occurs when I try to post a GET method to a rest api, but in postman it is working perfectly.

```
 public cartview() {
    let localaccesstoken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let apiUrl = this.urlService.apiUrl+'cart?access_token='+localaccesstoken;
    console.log(apiUrl);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("test : "+apiUrl);
        this.http.get(apiUrl)
          .subscribe(res => {
            console.log("w3cert Url : "+JSON.stringify(res));            
            console.log(resolve(res));
          }, (err) => {
            console.log('w3cert : '+reject(err));
        });
    });
```

In console log it shows an api. I copied that api and posted in postman and it is working, but in the app it shows this error:

> Error: "Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]"

Comment: I think error is not in api call error but in first line of your code. What is the type of localStorage variable. This may be of Storage type variable and injected in constructor. Plz try call using this keyword like this.localStorage.getItem('token');

Answer (score 1):

Change your method into something like this :

```
 public cartview() {
   let localaccesstoken = localStorage.getItem('token');
   let apiUrl = this.urlService.apiUrl+'cart?access_token='+localaccesstoken;
   console.log(apiUrl);
   return this.http.get(apiUrl).pipe(
     tap(res => console.log(res))
   ).toPromise() <--- rxjs wraps the observable in a Promise for you
 });
```

I figure the above should be somthing like a service method. So then in your component (or where you want to catch the promise) you can call the .then() method:

```
...cartview().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

From the above code, I can see you're not working well with observables / promises and also, you're logging the resolve/reject methods itself, not it's results.

Comment: i tried above code it show [Cannot find name 'tap'.]  @Francisco

Comment: you do need to import it from rxjs operators

Comment: import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: after tried that code in provider. when i call that response in ts page.
cartpage(){
    this.cart.cartview().then((result) => {
    })
  }
it shows an error like this
[Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.]

Comment: is that a typescript error ? why would you call this in a provider ? try declaring the type of the return in the method, something like : `public cartview(): Promise<any> {...`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from where you call your `cartview()` function
you should call it with then AND catch both :

```
cartview().then(res => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
})
```